# nodejs fs.chmodSync(path,'777') add newline

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, fs

i have a js object and writing its content to files using a loop and changing its permission.

```
for (var i = inputs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  fs.writeFileSync(
    Execute.path +
    Execute.folder +
    "/inputFile"+i,
    inputs[i],
    'utf-8'
   )

  console.log("Input file was saved!"+i);

  fs.chmodSync(
    Execute.path +
    Execute.folder +
    "/inputFile"+i,
    0777
  );
}
```

i got desired permission but it adds a \n at the end of file for example 55\n etc. but if i remove chmod its fine with 55, but permissions are not desrable.

i want to execute this file using a exec('sh script.sh) file.

Comment: Cache that file location, since you're using it more than once. That said, this is a node script, why would you exec that using `sh`? Why not just run it directly?

Comment: without sh it still says permission denied

Comment: so the obvious question is: what are the permissions for each inode in that filepath? Did you verify that when your script runs, it actually has chmod rights at all? Console log the `Execute.path` and `Execute.folder` values, and verify that your script would have mode-widening rights. 777 is pretty insane, so it's entirely possible you set up your computer to not allow that except when issued by superusers.